# Code to Find sheets whose name entered in column A and hyperlink it

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I am making a program which will create new worksheets and make them hyperlinks.
Currently I am facing a small problem.

Here is my code:

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim row2 As Integer

row2 = 10

For Each wks In Worksheets
    Select Case LCase(wks.Name)
    Case "summary-nca", "summary-gh-sample", "summary-ch-sample", "coa ledger"
        Debug.Print "Skipping " & wks.Name
    Case Else
        wks.Hyperlinks.Add ws.Cells(row2, 1), "", "'" & wks.Name & "'!A10", , wks.Name

        row2 = row2 + 1
    End Select
Next wks
```

In this code, it skips some specific sheets. I need a modification so that there is a list in column A for worksheets. The program should match the column figures with sheets name in the workbook and then hyperlink it.

Answer (score 1):

I interpreted your question to mean that the hyperlink should be in the list itself.

```
Sub hlws()
    Dim wks As Worksheet, mtch As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))  '<~~ define the WS list range!!!
            .Hyperlinks.Delete
            For Each wks In Worksheets
                mtch = Application.Match(wks.Name, .Columns(1), 0)
                If Not IsError(mtch) Then
                    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(mtch, "A"), _
                                    Address:="", _
                                    SubAddress:=Chr(39) & .Cells(mtch, "A").Value2 & "'!$A$1", _
                                    TextToDisplay:=.Cells(mtch, "A").Value2
                End If
            Next wks
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

This roughly duplicates your own code with the addition of a [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) that verifies the worksheet's existence in the list. Make sure you set the list range correctly before running the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. It will write the hyperlink list to a tab called "Main", which you can always change, or just put in whatever the value is of your Worksheet Object "ws" (this isn't shown in your code and neither is a declaration):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim row2 As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    row2 = 10
    Set ws = Sheets("Main")

    For Each wks In Worksheets

        Select Case LCase(wks.Name)

            Case "main", "summary-gh-sample", "summary-ch-sample", "coa ledger"

                Debug.Print "Skipping " & wks.Name

            Case Else

                wks.Hyperlinks.Add ws.Cells(row2, 1), "", "'" & wks.Name & "'!A10", , wks.Name
                row2 = row2 + 1

            End Select

    Next wks

End Sub
```